# (Unknown queue MSG=requested queue not found)

Tags: torque

I am trying to run wien2k jobs with torque job scheduler (maui scheduler) in ubuntu 14.04 . the app is installed correctly without any error messages but when add the bash script , I encounter with this error "qsub: submit error (Unknown queue MSG=requested queue not found)". I read about this error in [this website](https://www.hlrn.de/home/view/Service/FAQ).

can any one help me please?
it's my PBS Queue Manager after using qmgr -c "p s" command:

Create queues and set their attributes.

Create and define queue batch

create queue batch

set queue batch queue_type = Execution

set queue batch max_running = 20

set queue batch resources_max.ncpus = 20

set queue batch resources_max.nodes = 20

set queue batch resources_default.ncpus = 1

set queue batch resources_default.nodect = 1

set queue batch resources_default.nodes = 1

set queue batch resources_default.walltime = 76790:53:51

set queue batch enabled = True

set queue batch started = True

set server attributes.

set server scheduling = True

set server acl_hosts = seconduser

set server acl_hosts += firstuser

set server managers = root@localhost

set server managers += secfir@localhost

set server operators = root@localhost

set server operators += secfir@localhost

set server default_queue = batch

set server log_events = 511

set server mail_from = adm

set server scheduler_iteration = 600

set server node_check_rate = 150

set server tcp_timeout = 300

set server job_stat_rate = 45

set server poll_jobs = True

set server mom_job_sync = True

set server keep_completed = 0

set server next_job_number = 47

set server moab_array_compatible = True

set server nppcu = 1

Answer (score 1):

Try running:

```
qmgr -c "p s"
```

Look through the config for queue names. If there is a routing queue try submitting your job with qsub -q queuename jobfile . If a routing queue doesn't exist you can try execution queues. Otherwise, it may be best to ask the cluster admin since they have the power to kill your jobs if you don't do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem and fixed it. The fullest way to do a qsub is (described [here](https://www.msi.umn.edu/content/job-submission-and-scheduling-pbs-scripts))

> qsub -q queuename scriptname

Your queuename can be find using the command described in the previous answer, as you did

> qmgr -c "p s"

The result for yours (and mine as well) is that the queue name is "batch." Multiple lines determine this, such as "Create and define queue batch," and "create queue batch," but most assuredly:

> set server default_queue = batch

So, submit your job script with

> qsub -q batch scriptname